# Reference to this object in jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I use jQuery UI for a few widgets, like this:

```
$('.mySlider').slider({
    create: function() {
        // slider was created
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        // slider value changed
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        // slider was moved
    }
});
```

As these are all events, `this` does not refer to the anonymous slider options object but to the triggering HTML element.

But how can I exchange data between these methods? For example, I extract a few values from the DOM on `create` and want to have these values on `slide`. jQuery UI's callback parameters `event` and `ui` are no help in this case.

Comment: You can store information via the [jQuery `.data()` API.](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: Thanks for this idea - that could be a good workaround. (Anyway, I still find it hard to believe that I can't access the object I'm working with.)